# SQL Query: Identify similar values in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table which contains similar data.

```
To  From    Rule
01  02  E
01  03  E
01  04  E
02  03  E
02  01  E
03  02  E
04  01  E
```

So, 01-02 are same as 02-01. I want to write a query to have **unique pairs**. 
Result set should either contain **01-02 or 02-01** but not both.

I have gone through many posts but not able to figure out how to achieve this. 
If anyone has faced this problem please suggest the solution.

**Result Set Expected:**

```
To  From    Rule
01  02  E
01  03  E
01  04  E
02  03  E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and easy returning the exact result you are willing to get.

```
SELECT * from
(
  select
 (case when _to<_from then _to else null end) as _to,
 (case when _from>_to then _from else null end) as _from,
 _rule
 from _work
) as [Stay_happy_:P]
 where 
 _to is not null and _from is not null
```

I created the test environment of your data and selected it via above query--> [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca94b/6)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to normalise data.
One way to do it, is to swap From and To so that the smaller value is always in From.

Then you use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) window function to calculate groups.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ( SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY
            -- If From is bigger than To than swap them
            ( CASE WHEN [To] < [From] THEN [To] ELSE [From] END ),
            ( CASE WHEN [To] < [From] THEN [From] ELSE [To] END ) ORDER BY NULL ) AS PairNum
    FROM [some table] ) AS Groups
WHERE PairNum = 1
```

**Note:** if your version of SQL Server complains about `ORDER BY NULL` then replace `NULL` with some column name e.g. `ID`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve Your problem

```
select [To],[From] from #temp_t where [To]<[From]
union 
select [From],[To] from #temp_t where [From]<=[To]
```

Comment: you need to cater for scenario where [To] = [From]

Comment: @Alex I think now it will include condition [From]=[To]

Answer (score 0):

Try this scripts,

```
create table #t  (id int identity(1,1),Tos varchar(10) not null
,Froms varchar(10) not null,Rules varchar(10))


insert into #t VALUES
 ('01','02','E'),('01','03','E')
,('01','04','E'),('02','03','E')
,('02','01','E'),('03','02','E')
,('04','01','E')

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT t.*
        ,c.id id1
    FROM #t t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT *
        FROM #t c
        WHERE c.id > t.id
            AND c.tos = t.froms
            AND c.Froms = t.Tos
        ) c
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT t.*
    FROM #t t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM cte c
            WHERE c.id = t.id
                OR c.id1 = t.id
            )
    )
SELECT tos
    ,froms
    ,rules
FROM cte

UNION ALL

SELECT tos
    ,froms
    ,rules
FROM cte1

DROP TABLE #t
```